# How can I define the return type of a lodash reduce function with Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am trying to define the output of this Typescript function.

```
function (data: { topicId: number; subTopicId: number; topicName: string; subTopicName; string; }[] ) {
            var output = <IAnything>{
                dataMap: _.reduce(data, function (rv, v) {
                    rv[v.subTopicId] = v;
                    return rv;
                }, {});
```

I could map some parts which I didn't include in this question but I am getting confused on how to make the dataMap field. Can someone help me and tell me how I can map the output of the lodash _.reduce in the interface below. From what I can see the output of this reduce is:

```
data: { topicId: number; subTopicId: number; topicName: string; subTopicName; string; }[]
```

but how can I represent this and how can I represent the subTopicId that is used for the index of the array?

```
interface IAnything {
    //data: { id: number; name: string; }[];
    dataMap: 
}
```

Here is what the dataMap output looks like:

```
{
 "1":{"topicId":1,
      "subTopicId":1,
      "topicName":"x",
      "subTopicName":"x"},
 "2":{"topicId":1,
      "subTopicId":2,
      "topicName":"x",
      "subTopicName":"x"},
 "62":{"topicId":10,
       "subTopicId":62,
       "topicName":"x",
       "subTopicName":"x"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interfaces should look like this:

```
interface IAnything
{
    dataMap: IMap
}

interface IData
{
    topicId: number;
    subTopicId: number;
    topicName: string;
    subTopicName; string;
}

interface IMap{
    [key: string] : IData;
}
```

Then your function would look like this:

```
function (data: IData[]){
    var output = <IAnything>{
        dataMap: _.reduce(data, function (rv: IData, v: IData)
        {
            rv[v.subTopicId] = v;
            return rv;
        }, {})
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am looking at this now.

Comment: I just noticed that it is not correct because I missed the construct `rv[v.subTopicId] = v;` which will compile but this property won't be visible in TypeScript during editing. Instead creating a property like this dynamically I would pre-create a property even on another interface (for example IMap) and use it as type of dataMap in IAnything. This IMap would have any properties you need and in reduce func you would be just passing objects to them instead creating new properties dynamically.

Comment: I added the output of dataMap so you could see in more detail as I also realized there is maybe some problem with the mapping. As far as IMap. Can you give me an example of what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while. I just updated my answer to include what I mentioned with IMap interface. It is also based on what Radim Köhler mentioned in your other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000239/is-it-possible-to-define-an-object-containing-objects