# Variable keys in typescript as object members

Tags: typescript

I'm looking to make an interface for an object that has strings for keys mapping to string values. This seems like a fairly straightforward thing to do, but I haven't been able to

Error is shown [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20ISomeQuestions%20%7B%20%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3Astring%5D%20%3A%20string%3B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20var%20x%3AISomeQuestions%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22question1%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%22question2%22%3A%20%22%22%2C%0D%0A%09%20%20%20%20%22a%22%3A%20%22%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(x.question1)%3B)

I've checked out 
[Is it possible to define an object containing objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000239/is-it-possible-to-define-an-object-containing-objects/25001596#25001596) and
[Enforcing the type of the indexed members of a Typescript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315131/enforcing-the-type-of-the-indexed-members-of-a-typescript-object) but I couldn't access the values correctly.

Here's the code

```
interface ISomeQuestions { 
    [key:string] : string; 
 }
 var x:ISomeQuestions = {
    "question1": "",
    "question2": "",
    "a": ""
};

console.log(x.question1);
```

The last line reflects what I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. Since it only has the index signature that is what you need to use.

```
console.log(x['question1']
```